# What's another way of saying "frontest"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to come up with a phrase that could replace "frontest" in "Look at that man in the frontest row," as frontest is not officially correct grammar. I know I can say "Look at that man in the farthest back row," but I can't figure out a decent way to imply the opposite.

Comment: You could say "closest", if they're facing you.

Comment: Most people use 'front row'. It's ungradeable.

Comment: "The first row" is also good

Answer (score 2):

The word you are looking for is **frontmost**:

> Nearest to the front; furthest forward.
>
> ‘we chose the frontmost seats we could’
> <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/frontmost)</sub>

The opposite of this word is, of course, [backmost](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/backmost).

Answer (score 0):

Simply using "Look at that man in the front row," would be perfectly fine.

Depending on the position of the reader/speaker you might also say "Look at that man in the nearest/closest row.

Answer (score 0):

"Farthest in the front" is the opposite, and very much an option.

That said, I don't think anybody actually says "in the farthest back row". You'd say "in the last row" instead, or "in the very last row" if you need additional emphasis.

Likewise, the frontmost row is just called the first row. Or the very first row. Or, well, the frontmost row if you absolutely have to.

Comment: 'In the farthest row back' sounds idiomatic, never mind acceptable, to my ears.